# dynamics ax workflow in iOS

Tags: ios, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I want to mobilize Dynamics AX Workflow approvals on iOS. Can you please suggest how I can proceed on this.

I reviewed the Dynamics Business connector but it doesn't seem to have any classes specific to  Workflow.

Also came across Dynamics on the go, a application which allows users to approve workflow from their iOS smartphone. The pre-requisite being to install a connector on the dynamics workstation.

Answer (score 0):

http://daxmusings.blogspot.com/2011/11/10-minute-app-windows-phone-7-app.html

^ Should give you an idea about connecting to the AOS from a mobile

heres a 2009 example, I imagine the approach would be similar: http://workflowax.wordpress.com/category/mobile/